# Word 2010 macro not working

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a Word document that imports data from an Excel spreadsheet. Neither of the files are mine; I've inherited the issue. In the previous version of the Excel spreadsheet, the data was located in columns Q to T. In the new version it is located in columns R to U. The code used is below. When I run the previous versions of the document there are no issues. As soon as I do the import with a new document it breaks with this error code:

> 5941 - The requested member of the collection does not exist

The debugger highlights the code `ElseIf cel.Value <> ""` as the issue. The new code is below. (The old code that worked is the exact same, with the exception of the range as described above).

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub ImportComplianceResults()

    Dim fd As FileDialog, oApp As Excel.Application, oWb As Excel.Workbook, iWs As Integer, rData As Excel.Range

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        'Open modal window
        .Title = "Select file to import:"
        .InitialFileName = "X:\Template\"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xlsx"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
            Set oApp = New Excel.Application
            Set oWb = oApp.Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1), , True)
            'Check for worksheet in selected file
            For Each ws In oWb.Worksheets
                If ws.Name = "Compliance Results" Or ws.Name = "Résultats de conformité" Then iWs = ws.Index
            Next ws
            If iWs > 0 Then
                Set rData = oWb.Worksheets(iWs).Range("R10:T10,R13:U15,R17:U17,R19:U19,R21:U21,R23:U23,R25:U25,R27:U27,R29:U29,R32:U34,R37:U39")
                With ActiveDocument
                    For Each cel In rData
                        If IsError(cel.Value) Then
                            .SelectContentControlsByTag(cel.Address).Item(1).Range.Text = "#N/A"
                        ***ElseIf cel.Value <> "" Then
                            .SelectContentControlsByTag(cel.Address).Item(1).Range.Text = Format(cel.Value, cel.NumberFormat)***
                        Else
                            .SelectContentControlsByTag(cel.Address).Item(1).Range.Text = " "
                        End If
                    Next cel
                End With
                MsgBox "Data imported successfully.", vbInformation
            Else
                MsgBox "No data exists in selected file." & vbCr & "Import cancelled.", vbCritical
            End If
            oWb.Close False
            'Cleanup Resources
            Set rData = Nothing
            Set oWb = Nothing
            Set oApp = Nothing
        Else
            MsgBox "Import cancelled.", vbCritical
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
ElseIf Not cel.Value = "" Then
   .SelectContentControlsByTag(cel.Address).Item(1).Range.Text = Format(cel.Value, cel.NumberFormat)
```

Comment: Thanks David!  I've tried your suggestion and it doesn't break anything, which is good.  But as soon as I try the import again with the correct range, it doesn't work again.  I'm thinking there is just something I am not seeing within the range.  There are a total of 4 macros in the word document, could it be one of those issues where one of the other 3 are causing the issue and it's just breaking at this specific spot?

Answer (score 0):

Once you get over the error control, just the .Text property instead of .Value.

```
...
ElseIf cel.Text <> "" Then
    .SelectContentControlsByTag(cel.Address).Item(1).Range.Text = cel.Text
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  When I do so, it breaks at that point.  What I did was modified the range back to the old way and it worked (with data not in the right places mind you) but when I made this modification it didn't work :(